# Partial Derivative with Respect to y = ax²

Tags: derivatives

First of all sorry if my question seems too obvious, but I have been unable to find the answer to this anywhere and I want to be sure.

Assume I have the equality  $y= a x^2$

Now assume I am calculating the partial derivative of a function $L = x^2 + z$. Should I treat $x^2$ as $\frac{y}{a}$ (in which case $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{a}$) or not (in which case $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = 0$).

Comment: Yes you should treat $x^{2}$ as $\frac{y}{a}$

Comment: If $L(x,y,z):=x^2+z$, $\partial L/\partial y=0$ as $y$ does not appear in the formula. Things can be different for another definition of $L$.